# Using methods in html template angular 2+

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

What is the difference between using methods in html template that return `true` or `false`, and writing directly these conditions in html template angular 2+?

It is particularly interesting how often the first and the second method will be called?

example:

```
<div *ngIf="array && array.length && (array.property === true)">test</div>
```

or

```
<div *ngIf="isArrayProperty()">test</div>

public isArrayProperty() {
 return array && array.length && (array.property === true);
}
```

Comment: Which do you find more readable? More testable, in terms of unit tests? More maintainable? What happens if the logic changes? Are you going to copy/replace a bunch of templates or adjust perhaps a single helper method that many templates use?

Comment: @Alexander Staroselsky you are absolutely right from readability and maintainable point of view. But according to this experiment http://spraso.com/functions-in-angular-expressions-are-killing-your-performance/ 
>> The problem here is that the use of method calls leaves Angular in a position where on each change detection cycle it does not know for sure if the data has changed without calling the methods to retrieve the value. Is there any difference how change detection works for these examples?

Comment: @AliakseiManiuk That article does a great job to describe the issue at hand but doesn't necessarily compare performance of having function logic in the template vs component code. That being said their solution is to entirely remove function expressions from the template. The performant solution would probably be to prepare/check the data in something like `ngOnInit()` before it is rendered as the article did.

Answer (score 2):

The primary difference as Alexander Staroselsky has pointed out is maintainability and readability. In general logic should reside within your type script files, and not within your view. The more you can break out logic and view the easier your site will be to maintain.